# Adapt file path to UNIX- or Windows-style related to VS Code setting "python.terminal.activateEnvironment"

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code, python-venv

In the `.vscode/settings.json` of my current workspace, I have:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

It works upon opening an integrated `PowerShell` terminal, but both `MINGW64 bash` and `WSL` fail like so:

```
username@hd1pcms0347:/mnt/c/Users/username/Projects/projname$ source c:/Users/username/Projects/projname-venv/Scripts/activate
-bash: c:/Users/username/Projects/projname-venv/Scripts/activate: No such file or directory
```

Of course, I can *manually* adapt the file path from

```
c:/Users/username/Projects/projname-venv/Scripts/activate
```

to

```
/c/Users/username/Projects/projname-venv/Scripts/activate
```

for the `MINGW64 bash` shell, or

```
/mnt/c/Users/username/Projects/projname-venv/Scripts/activate
```

for the `WSL` shell, to make it work.
Yet, this is suboptimal as it will always *require my manual intervention*.

**How** can I achieve that this file path will have **automatically** either UNIX- or Windows-style **depending on the terminal-type** I open?

---

**Edit:** add screenshot of integrated terminal in VS Code

[image: vs-code-integrated-terminal-view]

Comment: Check out https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196690

Answer (score 0):

You should reselect the python interpreter before you create a new terminal using the remote server.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As far as I could understand what you mean, this did not resolve my problem (see screenshot 'vs-code-integrated-terminal-view' above in the edit of my OP). Maybe, you could add some details and be more precise on how to proceed step by step. Thanks a lot in advance :)